# Readers-writers problem using wait notify

Tags: java, concurrency

[Description of the Readers–writers problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem).

It looks like it works, but I have some doubts:

```
class ReadWriteBuffer<T> {

    private static final Object writeLock = new Object();

    private static final Object readWriteLock = new Object();

    private int numberReaders = 0;

    private int numberWriters = 0;

    private int numberWriteRequests = 0;

    public void write(T object) throws InterruptedException {

        numberWriteRequests++;

        synchronized (readWriteLock) {
            while (numberReaders > 0) {
                readWriteLock.wait();
            }
        }

        synchronized (writeLock) {

            numberWriteRequests--;

            numberWriters++;

            System.out.println("Writer #" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " started writing.");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            System.out.println("Writer #" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " finished writing.");

            numberWriters--;

            synchronized (readWriteLock) {
                readWriteLock.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }

    public void read() throws InterruptedException {

        synchronized (readWriteLock) {
            while (numberWriters > 0 || numberWriteRequests > 0) {
                readWriteLock.wait();
            }
        }

        numberReaders++;

        System.out.println("Reader #" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " started reading.");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Reader #" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " finished reading.");

        numberReaders--;

        synchronized (readWriteLock) {
            readWriteLock.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}

class Reader implements Runnable {

    private final ReadWriteBuffer<Object> buffer;

    private int priority;

    public Reader(int priority, ReadWriteBuffer<Object> buffer) {
        this.priority = priority;
        this.buffer = buffer;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(priority);
                buffer.read();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class Writter implements Runnable {

    private final ReadWriteBuffer<Object> buffer;

    private int priority;

    public Writter(int priority, ReadWriteBuffer<Object> buffer) {
        this.priority = priority;
        this.buffer = buffer;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(priority);
                buffer.write("Object");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class ReadersWriters {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ReadWriteBuffer<Object> sharedBuffer = new ReadWriteBuffer<Object>();

        new Thread(new Reader(1, sharedBuffer)).start();
        new Thread(new Reader(700, sharedBuffer)).start();
        new Thread(new Reader(100, sharedBuffer)).start();
        new Thread(new Writter(2000, sharedBuffer)).start();
        new Thread(new Writter(4000, sharedBuffer)).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are your doubts?

Comment: f.e. not sure about counters, seems that they should be atomic

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This code in the `read()` method is broken:

> ```
> public void read() throws InterruptedException {
>
>     synchronized (readWriteLock) {
>         while (numberWriters > 0 || numberWriteRequests > 0) {
>             readWriteLock.wait();
>         }
>     }
>
>     numberReaders++;
>
>     System.out.println("Reader #" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " started reading.");
>     Thread.sleep(1000);
>     System.out.println("Reader #" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " finished reading.");
>
>     numberReaders--;
>
>     synchronized (readWriteLock) {
>         readWriteLock.notifyAll();
>     }
> }
> ```

Since `numberReaders` `++` and `--` is not in a synchronized block, it essentially may as well not happen as far as other threads are concerned, or, worse, it could partially happen (like the `++` may happen, and the `--` may not).

Additionally, they may not produce the right results, anyway. The `++` operator is not atomic, and it is possible for the value to be `++` in two different threads at the same time, and the result to be just one increment for both invocations.

Bottom line is that, from a multi-threaded perspective, this code is broken.

References:

- [Is the pre-incriment operator thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7640533/1305253)
- [Java Concurrency in Practice (read this if you can)](http://jcip.net/)
- Java's [`ReadWriteReentrantLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html)